# Gradle Multi-Project Build: Plugin was not found

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I've got a very basic use case for a multi-project/multi-module Gradle build. What I ultimately need is no more structurally complex than is proposed in the official Gradle documentation [for declaring dependencies between subprojects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies_between_subprojects.html#sec:project_jar_dependencies).

Copying their documentation here, we have this project structure:

```
.
├── buildSrc
│   ...
├── api
│   ├── src
│   │   └──...
│   └── build.gradle
├── services
│   └── person-service
│       ├── src
│       │   └──...
│       └── build.gradle
├── shared
│   ├── src
│   │   └──...
│   └── build.gradle
└── settings.gradle
```

And these build files:

```
// settings.gradle
rootProject.name = 'dependencies-java'
include 'api', 'shared', 'services:person-service'

// buildSrc/src/main/groovy/myproject.java-conventions.gradle
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.13"
}

// api/build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'myproject.java-conventions'
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':shared')
}
shared/build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'myproject.java-conventions'
}

// services/person-service/build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'myproject.java-conventions'
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':shared')
    implementation project(':api')
}
```

However, [when I actually try this](https://github.com/atb-brown/gradle-test-modules) and run `gradle build` from the project root, I get the following error:

```
Plugin [id: 'myproject.java-conventions'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)
```

Just for kicks, I tried adding a version, but predictably Gradle was just as grumpy and said it could not resolve the artifact. What am I doing wrong?

My Gradle version info:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.5.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-06-30 06:32:47 UTC
Revision:     66bc713f7169626a7f0134bf452abde51550ea0a

Kotlin:       1.3.72
Groovy:       2.5.11
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.7 compiled on September 1 2019
JVM:          11.0.8 (Oracle Corporation 11.0.8+10)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It looks to me like you found a problem with the documentation.

The file called `buildSrc/src/main/groovy/myproject.java-conventions.gradle` declares what is called a [precompiled script plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:precompiled_plugins). For this to work, you have to apply the plugin called `groovy-gradle-plugin` (for Groovy plugins) in the `buildSrc` project:

```
# buildSrc/build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'groovy-gradle-plugin'
}
```

After this, it should be able to find your custom `myproject.java-conventions` plugin. If so, you could create an issue on the [Gradle issue tracker](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues) to suggest that they add the above snippet to the samples in the documentation for [project dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies_between_subprojects.html#sec:project_jar_dependencies).

Comment: Good catch! Here's a more accurate example from the Gradle project: [Sharing build logic between subprojects Sample](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_convention_plugins.html)

Comment: This worked for me, thanks Bjørn. Something else that I noticed is that the top directory for the conventions plugins MUST be name `buildSrc`, which was not at all clear in the documentation. But I'll log an issue for Gradle to add the `build.gradle` to the directory.

Comment: @AustinBrown it would be cool if you could link the issue you are going to create here for future reference.

Comment: You're right! @thekuest Here is the link: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-multi-project-documentation-clarification/38108 (Their GitHub repo didn't seem to have any issue labels related to documentation, so this forum was the best place I could find to raise the issue.)

Comment: And for kotlin (build.gradle.kts):
`plugins {\`kotlin-dsl\`}`

Comment: I have an extension to this question. When I execute a task from  the root project, the build runs fine. But when  :
I run any subproject task, I do not succeed. Again, the message

Plugin [id: 'com.xyz.app.java-conventions'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)

How do we run tasks from the subproject only? Do we always have to refer to such goals only from the root?

Answer (score 2):

I've started out the same way as you and ran into the same problem. While Bjorn's answer might work for Java, for me it didn't solve the problem (for a kotlin implementation) as it also requires the `gradlePluginPortal()` in a `repositories` block.

So to add to the accepted answer, what worked best for me to start out is simply to run the `./gradlew init` task for a type `application`. See also the gradle docs on [Building Java Applications with libraries Sample](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_building_java_applications_multi_project.html). Here you should always get a running multi-project irrespective of implementation language.

In my own kotlin application (with groovy dsl for gradle) this rendered the following `buildSrc/build.gradle`:

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 */

plugins {
    // Support convention plugins written in Groovy. Convention plugins are build scripts in 'src/main' that automatically become available as plugins in the main build.
    id 'groovy-gradle-plugin'
}

repositories {
    // Use the plugin portal to apply community plugins in convention plugins.
    gradlePluginPortal()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.72'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go to settings --> Gardle and change the settings as shown, to allow your project to build, run, and even test using IntelliJ IDEA.
[screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVtJo.png)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who still has this issue after trying out previous answers.
Here is what solved mine with kotlin dsl:

**I am using kotlin gradle build.**
**Change your conventions plugin name from:**
`project.java-conventions.gradle`
To
`project.java-conventions.gradle.kts`

**Add the following plugins to your plugin project's "gradle.bild.kts" file**

```
plugins{
    `kotlin-dsl`
}
```

The official doc is misleading by showing the file name without the "kts" extension in their screenshot.
[image]

Comment: I just stumbled on this, too. However, even with `.kts` it says the plugin was not found.

Comment: Turns out I needed to specify `plugins { \`kotlin-dsl\` \`kotlin-dsl-precompiled-script-plugins\` }`. Maybe one of them is enough.

Comment: yea, my answer is based on the rest of the answers. `kotlin-dsl` is enough.